# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }    
}

   
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [
    {type: 'server', name: 'testServer', content: 'just a test'}
  ];    
}
```

So I am messing around with Angular and taking a course to get the better understanding but I keep getting this error when I try to pass the value from one component to another, saying I am missing a type value in app.html code **[element] ="serverElements** :

> Type '{ type: string; name: string; content: string; }[]'
> is missing the following properties from type
> '{ type: string; name: string; content: string; }': type, name, content

**app.html :**

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <app-server-element 
          *ngFor ="let element of serverElements" 
          [element]="serverElements">
        </app-server-element>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The error is telling you that an array of things does not have the same properties as a single thing. Note the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

currently you pass in the array `serverElements` but the sub component expects one single element.
use the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <app-server-element 
      *ngFor ="let element of serverElements" 
      [element]="element">
    </app-server-element>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool. Would be great, if you would mark my answer as solution